# Why are my table columns not recognized when using a FROM subquery in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am just starting to learn SQL, and I am having some trouble writing subqueries in the FROM clause.

For example, I am trying to write a query that will return the first name, last name, and hire date for the most recent hire in the employee table.

I have looked through all my notes, and searched online, and I just cannot understand what I am messing up. I must use a subquery in a from clause

```
select emp_lname, emp_fname, mosthire
from (select min(emp_hiredate) as mosthire
from employee) recenthire;
```

Whenever I run this, I get this error:

```
ORA-00904: "EMP_FNAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I have spelled everything correctly.
Could someone describe what I may be messing up?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in basic arithmetic, start from the inner parentheses (in SQL, that is the "subquery" in parentheses):

```
select min(emp_hiredate) as mosthire from employee
```

The result of this subquery is a "table" with a single column, mosthire. Then in your outer query you are trying to select from this inner query, but you are trying to select emp_lname and emp_fname from this single-column "table". That can't happen. emp_fname is an invalid column name for the subquery - that's what the error message is telling you.

Also, it is not clear you really wanted the inner query to be that way; you are selecting the earliest hire date among ALL EMPLOYEES:  the result will have not just one column but also a SINGLE ROW as well. Instead, you probably wanted a more advanced query, using the "group by" clause:

```
select emp_lname, emp_fname, min(emp_hiredate) as recenthire
from employee
group by emp_id
```

(assuming your table has a column emp_id; otherwise perhaps change the last line to group by emp_lname, emp_fname, although data may certainly include more than one employee with the name John Smith).

...although re-reading now, perhaps you are just trying to pick up the most recent hire across all employees? That's a different query... and wondering why you choose min(hire_date) and not max(hire_date). In that case you probably want (something closer to your first attempt):

```
select emp_lname, emp_fname, emp_hiredate
from employee
where emp_hiredate = (select max(emp_hiredate) from employee)
```